# --noscripting not preventing scripting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I've started my MongoDB server with the `--noscripting` option:

```
mongod --dbpath C:\MongoData --noscripting
```

However, I can still load JavaScript files and execute the code in them:

```
> load('/Users/d.banks/Documents/mongo-rocks/hello-world.js')
true
> Hello('Dave')
Hello Dave!
```

I assume that the script is running because it's client-side?
If that's the case, what determines if a script is client or server side?  If not, why is the script running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

```
load('/Users/d.banks/Documents/mongo-rocks/hello-world.js')
```

... is an example of client-side scripting. It is client-side because it runs in the client.

The startup option `--noscripting` disables server-side scripting i.e. Javascript which runs on the server. Examples of this include

- [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/where/): the `$where` is a JavaScript expression or function which is executed server-side
- [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/group/): the `$reduce`, `$keyf` and `finalize` parameters are Javascript functions which are executed server-side
- [`$mapreduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/mapReduce/): the `map` and `reduce` parameters are Javascript functions which are executed server-side

So, in summary `--noscripting` disables server-side scripting, it has no effect on client-side scripting. Server-side scripta are those which execute *on the server*, with the three listed above being the prime examples.

Comment: Is it _client-side because it runs in the client_ or does it run in the client _because it's client-side_?  Mind has just blown.

Comment: However, it's the methods the script uses that will determine where it's executed?  Is there no way to force a script to run on the server?

Comment: There's nothing inherently client (or server) side about any Javascript expression or function. The client (or server) sided-ness is an aspect of **where** it is run. So, when you load a JS file into your client (as you showed in your question) then that is run server side but when you _pass_ a Javascript function to the server (as you can do when using $where, $group or $mapreduce) then you are asking the server to run that on your behalf and that is, therefore, server-side Javascript.

Comment: In answer to this: "Is there no way to force a script to run on the server?" ... in order for the server to run the script you need some way to _pass_ it to the server and $where / $group / $mapreduce all expose parameteers which allow you to pass JS to the server. Once passed to the server, this JS will be executed on the server. However, this: `load('/Users/d.banks/Documents/mongo-rocks/hello-world.js');` is not passed to the server and it will only ever be invoked client side.